# How do i bold the text in a php str_replace function?

Tags: php, xml, foreach, str-replace

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("xmldocumentation.xml") 
   or die("Error: Cannot create object");


 foreach($xml->children() as $pages){
   foreach($pages->children() as $page => $data){
   echo $data->id;
   echo '<br>';
   echo $data->timestamp;
   //echo $data->revision;
   echo "<br />";
   echo str_replace("/===[^=]+===/","bold heading here", $data->text);
   echo '<p class="text">'.$data->text.'</p>';

  }
}

?>
```

Using php how do i bold the text replaced by php's str_replace function and display the modified content with bold headings ie. ' **=== Heading ===** '?

Thanks

Comment: `str_replace()` doesn't accept a regex as the search string. You're looking for `preg_replace()`.

Comment: `<b>` usually does it for most people...

Comment: @MarcB irrelevant to what user is asking assuming `.text` already has the bold, and `<b>` tag is highly disencouraged to be used.

Comment: @TheDeadLike: still valid in html5, even if discouraged.

Comment: @MarcB Yep, thus I haven't said a thing about validity, it's just that it's a generic function tag(which simply bolds).

Comment: Are you trying to parse wiki text?  http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Parsing_wikitext

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
    echo str_replace("/===[^=]+===/","bold heading here", $data->text);
```

to

```
    $data->text = preg_replace("/===([^=])+===/","<strong>$1</strong>", $data->text);
```

You need `preg_replace` for regex, and need to capture the text you want to bold (via the `()`), and then enclose that text in an HTML element that will give you the desired formatting.

Comment: How does the $1 variable get set? Is this variable obviously returned from the preg_replace matches?

Comment: The `()` captures everything that is matched, and returns it in the `$1` variable (with is only accessible in that `preg_replace` - it's not like it created a PHP variable). If you had multiple `()`, you'd have multiple variables available, i.e. `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A `<b> </b>` can do the trick!

```
$strlst = 'lorem ipsum';

$strlst = explode( ' ' , $strlst );
function wrapTag($inVal){
   return '<b>'.$inVal.'</b>';
}
$replace = array_map( 'wrapTag' , $strlst );

$Content = str_replace( $strlst , $replace , $Content );

echo $Content;
```